# App Crashing when main returns with "Should've been invalidated"

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, crash, program-entry-point

App crashing when main returns.

Does anyone know what the console message "Should've been invalidated" means? I ran Clang and received a clean test result. I am successfully parsing JSON with Stig Brautaset's library like so:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
  ...
  NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];
  ...
}
```

Error:
EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

**Console Message**
2012-01-21 08:57:55.817 wftd-remote-json[14190:707] Should've been invalidated

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   @autoreleasepool {

     return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

**Console Message**
2012-01-21 08:57:55.817 wftd-remote-json[14190:707] Should've been invalidated

Thanks for looking at this

Comment: Post some code from your JSON code, specifically any code having to do with `wftd-remote-json`.

Comment: What JSON deserializer are you using?

Comment: What line in the debugger is showing when the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS happens?

Comment: Inside the @autorelease block: `code` @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`code`
    }

Comment: Also try searching for zombie objects (NSZombieEnabled or Instruments) as EXC_BAD_ACCESS is often caused by memory management issues and might even not be related to that console message.

Comment: So after profiling in Instruments, it looks like I have a zombie: "An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0x68955a0." Will try to relate this memory address to a line in my source code

Comment: By using Instruments, I was able to find the Zombie object and correct my error. All fixed. Thanks to TriPhoenix for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Instruments, I was able to find the Zombie object and correct my error. All fixed. Thanks to TriPhoenix for the suggestion.